# GAE sockets vs. Firebase

Tags: sockets, google-app-engine, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to develop an application where a number of clients should be able to see a list of elements. The elements in the list can be occupied by other users, so the users should be able to see when a given element is available/occupied.

The clients will fetch data via a REST API on GAE, and when they have fetched the list of elements, I imagined that I would create a socket connection for continuously updating the element list when the available/occupied status changed.

Reading the socket documentation for GAE lead me to the Channel API, which lead me to firebase https://cloud.google.com/solutions/using-firebase-real-time-events-app-engine

My question is: for an application as the above, should I use sockets (I cannot determine from the documentation whether I would be able to create sockets to clients?) or Firebase?
If I should use Firebase, how will this work seen from the client side - e.g. android/ios apps - they are supposed to use the SDK's to access the Firebase datastore?
I want the clients to contain as little logic as possible.

-Lull

Answer (score 0):

With Firebase, you don't have to worry about sockets and connections if you use any of the provided client SDKs.  It handles all the connection logic.  You just indicate the location of the data you want to observe, and it will call your listener whenever there is a change.